# Weird behavior with SimpleDateFormat on Android

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse this value `2013-10-22T16:21:22Z` using the following pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` and it throws this exception :

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-10-22T16:21:22Z" (at offset 19)
```

Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: The trailing '`Z`'? That's what's at offset 19.

Comment: @blahdiblah i can't change the value so my quesion is how can i change the pattern to work with the given value?

Comment: Throw a `'Z'` in at the end of your pattern?

Comment: Even with the Z at then i keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can parse the Z. Have you tried something like this?

```
String formattedTime = myTime.replace("Z", "+00:00");
```

And then tried parsing that?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, throw away the legacy java way to handle date and times. Instead, take a look at the Joda API [site](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). In their site you'll find a few code examples about the most common usages related to date and time manipulation, and probably some dealing with your question.

Comment: It seems like a big library for an android application. no?

Comment: I think not, taking into account that library has been added as a standard api on Java 8. Have you tried it out?

Answer (score 0):

simply,  'Z' is reserved keyword for datetime parsing. you can escape it like this:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
```

If you want to know what Z means. please visit here. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html